# hostapd problems

Tags: networking, drivers, hostapd

I want to use my Ubuntu server as a WLAN Access Point.

I configured it with this tutorial: http://www.sempervideo.de/pi-wifi.txt

However, it didn't work.

---

Then I ran `hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf`

The output was:

```
Configuration file:/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

nl80211: Could not configure driver mode.

nl80211: deniet ifname=wlxec086b123a02 disabled_11b_rates=0

nl80211: driver initialization failed.

wlxec086b123a02: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED

wlxec086b123a02: AP-DISABLED

hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlxec086b123a02 wasn't startet
```

I'm using this WLAN device: `TP-Link TL-WN722N`

It's suppose to work with it.

Does someone know what to do?

Sorry for posting this the twice. First time I messed it up :/

Comment: Possibly related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/427903/hostapd-does-not-create-a-wifi-network?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem just like this. It turned out that the driver for my adapter was not installed. Here is how I fixed it:
Run

```
dmesg
```

in the terminal. Look through the output for the information about the adapter. One of the items should be the chipset of the adapter. Then go online and search for the driver for that chipset. Methods of installing the driver will likely vary; hopefully the source wil provide instructions. I found that you need to leave nl80211 as the driver listed in the config file. Running

```
hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

should now work.